# Getting 404 error when attempting to use Apache rewrite on dokuwiki

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dokuwiki

I am building a wiki using dokuwiki, and am using the nice URL feature which uses url rewriting through Apache on the webserver, to get rid of the ugly php urls. My problem is that I seem to be only getting 404 Not Found errors when searching for the pages using the new URLs.

This is the .htaccess file provided, and the RewriteBase is pointed to the correct location.

```
#Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

## make sure nobody gets the htaccess, README, COPYING or VERSION files
<Files ~ "^([\._]ht|README$|VERSION$|COPYING$)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

## Uncomment these rules if you want to have nice URLs using
## $conf['userewrite'] = 1 - not needed for rewrite mode 2
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^_media/(.*)              lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_detail/(.*)             lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_export/([^/]+)/(.*)     doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$                        doku.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule (.*)                      doku.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$               doku.php

## Not all installations will require the following line.  If you do,
## change "/dokuwiki" to the path to your dokuwiki directory relative
## to your document root.
RewriteBase /dokuwiki

## If you enable DokuWikis XML-RPC interface, you should consider to
## restrict access to it over HTTPS only! Uncomment the following two
## rules if your server setup allows HTTPS.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^lib/exe/xmlrpc.php$      https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Apache actually loads .htaccess files. You will probably need this in your Apache config:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Yep this was it, boy that makes me feel kinda dumb. I just changed servers and installed Apache on it, never re-configured it, thanks!